# How to resize file and then convert to base64?

Tags: flutter, dart

As in the question how to do this? I take image from camera and then I want to resize this because is to big. Then i want to convert this image to base64 to send on server. I know how to take a picture from camera and convert but dont know how to resize. I'm doing it like that. But how resize this image before convert to base64?

```
    var image;
    image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    List<int> imageBytes = await _image.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = await base64Encode(imageBytes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ImagePicker library has two properties for resizing the image `maxHeight` and `maxWidth`

Here's an example:

```
var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
              source: ImageSource.camera,
              maxHeight: 150.0,
              maxWidth: 150.0,
          );
```